# Edit & save Json with php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to change a value in a JSON file. I want to remove the part of the string after the dot from items in the `'Merchant'` key. For example, "Amazon.com" should be replaced with "Amazon".

Here is my code:

```
$file = 'myfile.json';
$jsonString = file_get_contents($file);
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);
foreach ($data as $key => $field){
    $data[$key]['Merchant'] = (explode(".",$data[$key]['Merchant']));
}
$newJSON = json_encode($data);
file_put_contents($file, $newJSON);
```

Here is my JSON File: (I want to replace everything after .[dot])

```
[
    {
        "0": {
            "Code": "No Voucher Code",                
            "Merchant": "Amazon.com",               
            "Title": "Upto 70% off on Toys, Kids Apparel and Stationary"

        },
        "1": {
            "Code": "No Voucher Code",
            "Merchant": "ebay.com",               
            "Title": "Set of 3 LED Bulbs @ Rs. 99 + Free Shipping"                
        }
```

Output: save and replace Merchant value

```
[
    {
        "0": {
            "Code": "No Voucher Code",                
            "Merchant": "Amazon",               
            "Title": "Upto 70% off on Toys, Kids Apparel and Stationary"

        },
        "1": {
            "Code": "No Voucher Code",
            "Merchant": "ebay",               
            "Title": "Set of 3 LED Bulbs @ Rs. 99 + Free Shipping"                
        }
```

But my code is not changing the `"Merchant"` values. Why not?

Comment: exactly HOW is this code not working?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following approach with `json_decode` and `strstr` functions(I've taken a json data from the string for demonstration):

```
$jsonString = '[
    {
        "0": {
            "Code": "No Voucher Code",                
            "Merchant": "Amazon.com",               
            "Title": "Upto 70% off on Toys, Kids Apparel and Stationary"

        },
        "1": {
            "Code": "No Voucher Code",
            "Merchant": "ebay.com",               
            "Title": "Set of 3 LED Bulbs @ Rs. 99 + Free Shipping"                
        }
    }
]';

$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);

foreach ($data[0] as $key => &$v) {
    $v['Merchant'] = strstr($v['Merchant'], ".", true);
}
$newJSON = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

print_r($newJSON);
```

[DEMO link](https://eval.in/611790)

Comment: I agree that `strstr` seems better suited for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is in an outer array that you are not addressing. Instead of `$data`, you need to loop over `$data[0]`. You can do this more simply using a reference. Inside the loop, assign the first exploded element back to the `'Merchant'` key after using `explode`:

```
foreach ($data[0] as &$field){
    $field['Merchant'] = explode(".",$field['Merchant'])[0];
}
unset($field); // unset the reference to avoid weirdness if $field is used later
```